# Associations, Joins and Scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, associations

I have the following setup:

```
class Program
   has_many :participants
end

class Participant
   belongs_to :user
end

class User
   has_many :participants
end
```

I want class method or scope to return all the programs in which a certain user participates. Here's what I have so far:

```
def self.where_user_participates(user)
   Program.joins(:participants).where('participants.user_id' => user.id)
end
```

I believe that works but I am not in love with it. I prefer not to talk about 'id's but use the associations, but I could not get it to work, e.g.:

```
def self.where_user_participates(user)
  Program.joins(:participants).where('participants.user' => user)
end
```

How can I improve this? And is it true that official 'scope's are not needed and a class method is 'best practice' in Rails 3?

Comment: Try this `Program.joins(:participants).where(user: user)`

Comment: I did, it didn't work: Hirb Error: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: programs.user: SELECT "programs".* FROM "programs" INNER JOIN "participants" ON "participants"."program_id" = "programs"."id" WHERE "programs"."user" = 2

Comment: My bad: `Program.joins(:participants).where(participants: {user_id: user.id})` I don't think you can pass directly the user object. Use a scope to avoid that: `scope :for_user, lambda { |user| joins(:participants).where(participants: {user_id: user.try(:id) || user }` And use it like `Program.for_user(user)` where the variable "user" can either be an id (integer) or a User object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Program
  has_many :participants
end

class Participant
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :program
end

class User
  has_many :participants
  has_many :programs, :through => :participants
end
```

Then to get the programs call:

```
user.programs
```